# How to use azure function to read a json file url or a url text file that has json data into string?

Tags: json, azure

```
public static async Task<string> MakeSlackRequest(string message)
{
    var urlJsonData = "{'text':'message'}"; // I want my url with json data to convert into jsonstring
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var requestData = new StringContent("" + urlJsonData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync($"webhookURL", requestData);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have a url file(jsonData.json and jsonData.txt), anyone know how to convert a url file with jsonData.json or jsonData.txt into a string for azure function?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: The problem is how to use the url which has jsonData into string.

Comment: Sorry, can you try to explain more clearly? What URL? What does the variable `urlJsonData` represent and what does it have to do with URLs? You are passing the literal string "webhookUrl" to PostAsync which is clearly not correct but you haven't explained clearly which URL you do want.

Comment: For example:
http://time.jsontest.com/

This is a url with json data. The problem is how to use the url to get the body(json data) into string.

Comment: OK, so use that URL. It serves JSON back to my browser so it will probably want a GET not a POST so use GetAsync instead. You don't need to send it any content.

Comment: I tried the GetAsync, do you know what i'm doing wrong in this code? I got error and was stuck... using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://time.jsontest.com/");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }

Comment: What does "was stuck" mean?

Comment: URLs begin with a protocol, for web requests this must be http:// or https://

Comment: The stuck error is the missing http of the url, just added the http://, and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
var urlJsonData = client.GetStringAsync("url/sample.json").Result;
```